# Got kicked out of the office while on maternity leave

Tags: united-states, employer, parental-leave

While on maternity leave I was notified by the office supervisor that my office is given to someone else.  they packed all of my belongings prior to notifying me.  my office will be given to someone who will be there 1-2 days a week.  compared to me working there daily.  I am new to the job for about 4 months and went on maternity leave.  I feel as if my employer wants me to quit.  everyone else with the same position as me has an office in there and now they kicked me out after making the decision and packing my things.  I even ask the supervisor if the company want me to quit.  she reassures me that's not the case.  it's hard to swallow this.  any advice?

Comment: Why not just take this on face value? They just need to have the space for a while

Comment: @Kickout - how long is your maternity leave? Have you already returned and not been assigned a new office? Or are you going to be on maternity leave for an extended period? While it's not been brilliantly handled, it could easily be as simple as they've just seen an empty desk that could be put to use and will restore it you (or place you at a similar desk/office) on your return.

Comment: i was informed that I will not have an office.  just went on leave.

Answer (score 14):

Your supervisor has told you that the company doesn't want you to quit.

Therefore it's reasonable to assume that the company simply finds that your office space will be useful for someone else to work in while you're on leave.

When you return, you might be given your office back, or another one.

As your supervisor says, your office being temporarily offered to someone else doesn't mean that you're being canned.